# Cannot reset NSArray and NSMutableArray in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I create an `NSMutableArray` as follows (note that `winner` is an instance variable):

```
winner = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"11", @"12", @"13", nil];
```

When I set `winner` to `nil` or remove its objects like

```
[self.winner removeAllObjects];
```

my program will automatically shut down. How should I solve this?

Updated !!!
In case I code like this

```
self.winner = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"11", @"12", @"13", nil];
```

it will call setter method which is

```
- (void)setWinner:(NSMutableArray *)newWinner
{
    [winner release];
    winner = [newWinner retain];
}
```

Do I still need to retain the array like

```
self.winner = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"11", @"12", @"13", nil] retain];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you calling `-removeAllObjects` in a different method?  If so, then the problem is likely that you've failed to retain the array, and it has been destroyed between the assignment and your later reference. `+arrayWithObjects` returns an instance that has had `autorelease` called on it.

Either use a synthesized property to set the instance variable, use a method that returns ownership of the object (like `+alloc`), or add a `retain` call:

```
winner = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"11", @"12", @"13", nil] retain];
```

Answer (score 1):

You didnt allocated the array

SO do like,

```
winner = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:@"11", @"12", @"13", nil];
```

Comment: the array was allocated by calling `arrayWithObjects:...`.

Answer (score 1):

You assigned an autoreleased reference to an instance variable, so it gets dealloced after the event loop. Just retain it after creating it:

```
winner = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"11", @"12", @"13", nil] retain];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program is not shutting down for what you're showing there, there's nothing wrong with it. Show us what error code you get and whether an exception is being thrown and post a bit more code around where the crash is happening.